# Grails 3.0.1 showing error

Tags: grails

I am trying to create an application on grails and I am using grails.3.0.1. I am writing grails command grails create-app but everytime it is showing same error.[As given in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIM99.png)

I copied gradle.properties to C:\ but it is still not working.Any help would be apperciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grails create-app helloworld`

Answer (score 0):

You have no permissions to write in the C:\ folder. Open the terminal with administrator rights and try again.

For more information about the error use:

```
grails create-app helloworld --stacktrace
```